# Need help to select correct install file and options for BA\PDI

Tags: pentaho

We want to upgrade our Pentaho suite from 4.1 to 5.0 version. Currently we use Analyzer for ad hoc reporting (which is installed on linux box) and Kettle (which is on windows).Plus this time we want to install repository also so that our kettle jobs are shared centrally.

With this requirement I believe I need to install both BA and DI components, since Analyzer comes under BA. But I can see that BA and DI have separate repository.

Can someone help me explaining which install files I should run and what options should I pick ?. I have 3 files pdi-ee-5.0.2-dist.zip, pdi-ee-client-5.0.1-dist.zip and pdi-ee-server-5.0.2-dist.zip

I would also appreciate if someone can provide me with correct link or video to help me with the install\configuration.Right now I am referring to http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install anything, you just have to unzip the files and have to run appropriate batch file on windows and .sh file in linux.

For pentaho Data integration you have to run "spoon.bat" on windows and "spoon.sh" on linux

For pentaho BA Server you have to run you have to reach down to biserver-ce foler (i am using community addition) for you it may be like biserver-ee and under that you have to run "start-pentaho.bat" in windows and "start-pentaho.sh" in linux.

you can [refer this](http://docs.huihoo.com/pentaho/pentaho-business-analytics/4.8/install_pdi.pdf) link..